# while loop and condition when i click php

Tags: php, sql, loops

When i click, i want display a next item of my db like this

```
 for( $i = 0; $i < $count; $i++ ) {
        if(isset($_POST['yes'])){
            $select = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM node where id=:id');
            $select->bindParam(':id', $current_id_left);
            $select->execute();
            $nodes = $select->fetch();

            $current_id_left = $nodes->id_left_node_children;
            $current_id_right = $nodes->id_right_node_children;
            $current_question = $nodes->questions;
        }
```

it works but the loop gives me a last item. Before a last item, I have a second item which is not displayed.

How can i display item one by one ?

Comment: Do you want it act as pagination!

Comment: no, i create a binary tree. i have a first question and when i click on 'yes', i want to see a second question who is left etc. but here, i see directly a last item. thanks

Comment: You should accept the answer to the previous question,Give back to the community if you want help.

Comment: you prefer that I post a new question ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is you are using `$i` in your for loop. This is correct, but you need to use `$i` inside your code also. At the moment you are looping but doing the same execution every time. Here is a simple Example to help you.

```
for( $i = 0; $i < $count; $i++ ) {
  $x = $i;
  echo $x;
}
```

Comment: thanks. i know who is the problem but your code don't resolved it.